# Pixik brokes my website

Tags: matomo

I have a blog, programed by me in PHP. I use Piwik to track my visitors. I rewrite my website, in PHP with Symfony. I delete my old website except piwik and I put my new website. I use the same database and the same folder for piwik than before.

Now, when I go to Piwik, the first page works but after, my website is down during about ten minutes, Piwik and the all site. Chrome says the website is innacessible, with the error : ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I try to reinstall Piwik, with the last version, but I have the same problem : after the installation, when I go to the dashboard, the site is down.

I use a [shared server](https://www.firstheberg.com/en/shared-hosting-first-mini). Pwik works in the server with my precedent website or with Joomla!, on a website with some hundred vistors by day.

There are nothing in the logs, except index.htm and index.php

Why and how resolves this problem ?

Thanks,
Jérémie

Comment: You should ask your host.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: @MarcB sorry if this question is not appopriate. And because this problem appears after I rewrite my site, it's maybe an error in my code so I believed that I can ask here.

Comment: Then you should show any relevant code... We can't fix what we can't see.